# Help with proving that this series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have this complex series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, which I'm trying to prove converges.

Now, I know that a complex sequence converges iff both its real and its imaginary partial sums converge.

Obviously, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Im(a_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}0 \to 0$.

But, when I try to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Re(a_n),$ I end up with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$ which, whilst, intuitively, I know diverges, I can't seem to prove.
I know I have to use the Comparison Test, but to what should I compare it?

By the way, 'my' version of the Comparison Test is as follows (for divergence):
If $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ is bounded above and if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges.

Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Use the integral test to show that your series in question diverges. That's fairly easy to integrate

Comment: You have a sign error. The signs should alternate.

Comment: It will be easier if you use [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I have to use the Comparison Test; we haven't done either of these suggested tests.

Comment: You could, for your comparison test, use the harmonic series I believe.

Comment: You have done it, it was probably called the Alternating Series test.

Comment: Let us compute the first few terms. We get $\frac{i}{1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}+\cdots$. Note the sign alternation in both the real parts and imaginary parts.

Comment: @alexqwx Yes, as pointed out, in case of an alternating series the series does converge because it meets the prereqs for an alternating series test. It converges (conditionally) Have you gone over alternating series material, because that would be logical in my opinion here before trying to enforce the comparison test

Comment: @alexqwx, do you have to use a quotient method? Simply noting that  for every integer greater than 1, say n, 1/n > 1/n^(1/2) will be satisfied should be enough. I'd think.

Comment: @Just_a_fool Nope- never come across it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So, how would you write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Im(a_n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Re(a_n)$?

Comment: The imaginary part is $1-1/\sqrt{3}+1/\sqrt{5}-1/\sqrt{7}+\cdots$. The real part is $-1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{4}-1/\sqrt{6}+\cdots$. By the way, Comparison works with positive series, it is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Just_a_fool The form of the comparison test I know requires each term be bounded *in absolute value* by a real converging series.  In fact comparing with an alternating series is much harder and I do not know of a way to apply the comparison test in this case.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I mean in sigma notation. If you were trying to prove that the real and/or imaginary partial sums diverge (by the Alternating Series Test), could you just take the odd subsequence and show that that diverges?

Comment: The series *converges*. Sigma notation is irrelevant, but if you want, the real part is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k/\sqrt{2k}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Im(a_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}0 \to 0$.

This is not the case.

As  André Nicolas suggests in the comments, it is best to write out the first few terms to get a feel for the series:
$$
\frac{i}{\sqrt1}
 + \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}
 + \frac{-i}{\sqrt3}
 + \frac{1}{\sqrt4}
 + \frac{i}{\sqrt5}
 + \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}
 + \frac{-i}{\sqrt7}
 + \frac{1}{\sqrt9}
 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{10}}
 + \cdots
$$
You correctly observe that you should look at the real and imaginary parts.
\begin{align*}
\sum \Im (a_n) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}} + \cdots \\
\sum \Re (a_n) &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} - \cdots \\
\end{align*}

The proper way to show these converge is with the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

> If you were trying to prove that the real and/or imaginary partial sums diverge (by the Alternating Series Test), could you just take the odd subsequence and show that that diverges?

The alternating series test requires these two conditions:

1. The terms *alternate in sign*.
2. The terms *decrease in absolute value*.

The fact that every other term diverges does not help you.

**Note:** The comparison test in the form it is usually stated says that if a complex or real series is bounded *in absolute value* by a positive convergent series, then that series converges (absolutely).  You cannot apply this form of the comparison test to the above series, because the sum of the absolute values of the terms diverges (the series is *conditionally* convergent).